# Apply Style to all child-elements of specific type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I want to write a style for wpf where all buttons in a StatusBar (that has a defined style) have the same style (e.g. width).

Here is what my style looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBar}"
               x:Key="DialogBoxStatusBarStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="5" />

    ...?

</Style>
```

And the xaml for the elements:

```
<StatusBar Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DialogBoxStatusBarStyle}" Grid.Row="3"
               FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Button Content="Übernehmen"
                Width="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Button Content="Abbrechen"
                Width="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

        <Button Content="OK"
                Width="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </StatusBar>
```

In the final version I don't want to set width to 100 for all buttons. This should be defined in the style of the `StatusBar` or better say in the style of the button-childs of the `StatusBar`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add a default Style for Buttons to the `Resources` of your `DialogBoxStatusBarStyle`:

```
<Style TargetType="StatusBar" x:Key="DialogBoxStatusBarStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    ...
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

To extend on the answer above (@Clemens), you could even do something like this, to reuse a button style independently, and also apply it to children of a specific container.

Styles:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBar}" x:Key="DialogBoxStatusBarStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />

    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
    </Style.Resources>
    ...
</Style>
```